# Basemap - request values from NOAA Data

Tags: matplotlib-basemap, noaa

I am working on this [script](http://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/examples/usingpython.shtml) and need to query the **data object** that I get through `netCDF4` (first example) to retrieve values at a specific `latitude` and `longitude` coordinate. I am not sure how to index the data object in the example with lat/long in degrees or how to map coordinates onto a meshgrid and query from there. Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the NOAA sample script and with the help of the ww3 mail list, I figured this:

In order to get values from the data object, you do

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap,interp

lat = GPSLat
lon = (360 + GPSLon)  

value = interp(data, lon, lat, np.asarray( [[ (360+ GPSLon) % 360 ]] ), np.asarray( [[ GPSLat ]] ), checkbounds=True, masked=True, order=1)
```